# Is $B(x, r)=B \bigg(x, \frac{\text{diam}(B(x, r))}{2}\bigg)$ always true?

Tags: metric-spaces

Is it the case that if $B(x, r)$ is a ball in a metric space $X$, where $x\in X$, then $B(x, r)=B \bigg(x, \frac{\text{diam}(B(x, r))}{2}\bigg) ?$  I believe this is correct but I want to check, thanks. ($\text{diam}$ is the diameter)

Comment: $x$ is from any metric space?

Comment: @zkutch yes $x$ is in the metric space.

Comment: @zkutch i have edited the question to clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not true.

On the metric space $X = \lbrace 0, 2 \rbrace$ with the metric induced by the usual metric on $\mathbb{R}$, one has
$$B(0, 3) = \lbrace 0, 2 \rbrace$$

but $\mathrm{diam}(B(0, 3))=2$, and
$$B(0,1)= \lbrace 0 \rbrace$$

Comment: Thank you. then I think instead this is true $B(x, r)=B (x, \text{diam}(B(x, r)))$ ?

Comment: No :) In $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual metric, the diameter of $B(0,1)$ is $2$, and $B(0,1) \neq B(0,2)$...

Comment: of course, I think I need a break ^^

Answer (score 1):

We have $\operatorname{diam}(B(x,r)) \le 2r$.  In general, it is not equality.
In extreme cases, we could have $B(x,r) = \{x\}$ with $\operatorname{diam}(B(x,r))=0$.
In an [Ultrametric space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultrametric_space) we have $\operatorname{diam}(B(x,r)) \le r$.
In a normed vector space (over the real or complex numbers) we do have $\operatorname{diam}(B(x,r)) = 2r$.